# Youtube API in google apps scripts ..... where to get started with coding

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

i would like to use the Youtube API's with
Google Apps Scripts.

Unfortunately I am complete newbie and don't know Google Scripts.

Can someone please guide me to the link in which part of google apps
I can directly get started.

Thanks
Svenja

Answer (score 0):

learn Google Apps scripts

Learn Google cloud... simple things like making projects and which permission and api you will need in ur project

Use YouTube API in Google Apps Scripts

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/